# Call child method before parent Constructor in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Is it possible to call child method before parent constructor?

I have method in child class for define variables and then pass to parent class. After parent class receives variables, It'll apply to various attributes in class.

This is my relevant code.

Parent class

```
class CParent
{
  private $arrMember = array();
  private $mark;

  function CParent{
    /*
     * If parent constructor run first, init() method'll get blank array.
     */
    $this->setAttr();
  }      

  protected function init(){ return array(); }

  private function setAttr(){

    $arr = $this->init();

    foreach ($arr as $item){
      array_push($this->arrMember, $item['name']);

      if (isset($item['mark']) && $item['mark'] == TRUE)
        $this->mark = $item['name'];
    }
  }

}
```

Child class

```
class CChild extends CParent
{
  /*
   * I'd like to define variable within this method then pass to parent class.
   */
  protected function init(){
    return = array(
               array('name' => 'v1', 'mark' => true),
               array('name' => 'v2'),
               array('name' => 'v3')
             );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you instantiate the child the child's constructor function will execute first. It should be possible to pass a value to the parent's constructor from there. Take a look at PHP's magic methods - specifically `__construct()` - which you'll fine [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

Comment: *If parent constructor run first, init() method'll get blank array.* - no it won't, because you declared `init()` in your child class

Comment: @Mike W - Thanks it work but I still want to define variable within method.

Comment: @One Trick Pony - I tried, but it return blank array because parent class run first and at that moment method init() still blank.

Comment: @One Trick Pony - Thanks for advice but still same result.

Comment: [Works here](http://3v4l.org/Fn1hD)

Comment: @KKK Are you instantiating the **parent** class, or the **child** class?

Comment: @One Trick Pony - It work on example code but in my real code still not work. I'll take this code to reapply again. Thanks.

Comment: @nickb Instantiating in parent class sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the parent constructor in the child.

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->setAttr();
}
```

If you don't override the parent constructor, it will be called when you instantiate the child. However, if you override it, it will only be called if you do `parent::__construct()` from the child constructor.